# Is there a difference between using `transform: translate(...` and `translate: ...`?

Tags: css, css-transforms

I have noticed that in css. You can use (e.g.) `translate: 50% 50%` directly instead of `transform: translate(50%, 50%)`. Is the former a shorthand for the latter?.

I have tried to search for it but couldn't find anything.
same thing for `rotate` and probably for the rest of the transformation properties

And if it is a shorthand, why nobody uses it (I have never came across code that used it.)

Comment: Where did you see or why do you assume that using `translate: 50% 50%`  instead of `transform: translate(50%, 50%)` is valid?

Comment: css property called `translate` does not exist. Probably it's deprecated. What browser do you use?

Comment: I use the latest version of Firefox (92.0). I am not sure if it is valid but it has the same effect as `transform: translate(...)`.

Comment: Firefox supports this syntax, but it's not added to many browsers yet. Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/translate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties of `translate` (and `rotate`, and `scale`) currently appear only in [CSS Transforms Module Level 2, Editor’s Draft, <del>16 June 2021</del> 13 September 2023](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-2/) under the section [5. Individual Transform Properties: the translate, scale, and rotate properties](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-2/#individual-transforms):

> The `translate`, `rotate`, and `scale` properties allow authors to specify simple transforms independently, in a way that maps to typical user interface usage, rather than having to remember the order in `transform` that keeps the actions of `translate()`, `rotate()` and `scale()` independent and acting in screen coordinates.

The important part why it is suggest its `in a way that maps to typical user interface usage, rather than having to remember the order in transform` so it should make it easier to use those for their most common use-cases.

The support ([caniuse.com: translate](https://caniuse.com/?search=translate)) <del>is not really good</del> is at about 89.49% (2023-09-25): FF 72+ and Safari 14.1+, iOS Safari 14.5+

> Oh, so that why no body uses it. Pretty useless!

That's not necessarily true, if it can be translated to another css property, then you can already use it today if you have a tool like [postcss.org](https://postcss.org/) in your development chain, and if `postcss` has a plugin for translating it.

But it is not always clear if things that are currently only in the draft of the specification will really make it into the final version.

Comment: In: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/translate, it was stated that it is supported in iOS Safari 14.5+, not 14.7+. It doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: @H.B. fixed that.

Comment: FYI, support for the translate property seems pretty good nowadays https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/translate#browser_compatibility

Comment: @spuente Updated the answer. Most of the time, I don't really care about the browser support (if backward compatibility can be achieved with e.g. postcss), or if it is a purely nice to have addition to the design.